# tableView printout to printer missing column headers

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, printing

In my app I am using a button to print a tableview of information to a printer.  I am using the simple code below to print.  I get output fine and even in duplex mode.  I use the exact output table for a variety of reports.  My problem - How do I include a title and the column headers?

```
(IBAction)btnPrintTable:(id)sender {  
  NSPrintOperation *op;
  op = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:rptTable];
  if (op)      
    [op runOperation];
  else{      
    NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
    [alert setMessageText:@"No Table Data available for printing"];
    [alert setInformativeText:@"Cancel and create table data"];
    [alert setAlertStyle:NSWarningAlertStyle];   
    if ([alert runModal] == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn){}
  }
}
```

There are 6 column headers: Number: Extension: Year: Type: Price: Description:

I have read 'About MAC Printing' and 'Printing Programming Topics for Cocoa'.  I can not reference a table header/column design detail.  I can not find anything in pagination topics referencing this issue.  Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the type of rptTable ? Is it NSTableView ?

Comment: Need to get back to this issue. Yes it NSTableView.